# How to tell if external dependency (.aar) has been added properly?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I'm adding my first local library for work (named "libprinter-release" for your reference). I imported it using "Add new module and then declared it as a dependency in my app directory:

[image]

None of the methods that should be in that library are being made available when I go to use it. Have I done this right? Is there something else I need to do to get the library working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an `aar` file for your project, you should add the file to the `libs` directory under your module name. Then you need to update your app `build.gradle` by adding the `libs` flatDir and the library like this:

```
android {

   ...

}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  // change your-library to your library name.
  implementation(name: 'your-library', ext: 'aar')

  ...
  // other dependencies.

}
```

But if you're using a project module, you need to make sure if the module are using `implementation` or `api` with the dependencies. When you're using `implementation` with the dependencies, you need to add the same dependencies to your app module.

Last, if your `libprinter-release` and `libprinter-debug` are the same except the debug version has the debug flag on, you need to tell the `build.gradle` about it by using the following in your dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
  ...

  debugImplementation project(':libprinter-debug')
  releaseImplementation project(':libprinter-release')

  ...
}
```